# Running Another program from python

Tags: python, sys

I want to call a program multiple times from a python code, and save the output of that program in a text file. My first problem right now is just calling the other code. I have to redirect to a different directory and call ./rank on output.txt. This is how Im trying to do it:

```
    TheCommand = "~/src/rank-8-9-2011/rank output.txt"
    os.system(TheCommand)
```

but im getting a parsing error.

```
 [Parsing error on line ]Unknown error: 0
```

Im running python2.7 on Mac OS 10.5.8. Im not sure what the problem is. I also tried using subprocess:

```
 subprocess.call(["~/src/rank-8-9-2011/rank", "output.txt"])
```

This does not find the directory (I have a feeling Im using the subprocess incorrectly), but I dont know what is wrong with the os.system.

Answer (score 5):

the name of the program in the first argument to `subprocess.Popen` must not contain `~` as it doesn't pass the string to the shell for processing (which like always using parameterized queries in sql, protects one from string injection attacks, e.g. if instead of `output.text` one had `;rm -rf /`, the system version would run `rank` and then run `rm -rf .` but the `subprocess.Popen` would only have `rank` open a file named `;rm -rf .`), so one should expand it by calling `os.path.expanduser`:

```
subprocess.Popen([os.path.expanduser('~/src/rank-8-9-2011/rank'), "output.txt"])
```

although it is possible to turn shell processing on by passing `shell=True`, it is not recommended for the aforementioned reason.

Answer (score 2):

you should try http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser

```
import os.path
subprocess.call([os.path.expanduser("~/src/rank-8-9-2011/rank"), "output.txt"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain your parsing error is coming from `rank`, not from your os.system command, as nothing there looks weird.  What happens if you run `rank` manually?

`subprocess` seems to have a problem with '~', although I'm not immediately sure why.  Put the full path and it should work (although you'll likely get that parsing error if it is indeed a problem with `rank`).